# iOS dynamic layout possible?

Tags: ios

I am total beginner for iOS development and I would like to get some opinions on hooking my cms to iphone app.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

in cms, shop owner adds his products without category. and some shops with more products can create one level category(max two levels are allowed). I have a rest api that outputs either list of products or a list of categories depending what the shop owner ahave in cms.

in iphone app, I would like to display shop with categories with simple text list(one category name per row).

if shop has no category and just products, i will display two products per row with thumbnail(product name below the product thumbnail). This is the same layout when a category is clicked.

I have asked a friend who is familiar with iOS development and he said iOS needs to know the layout before display and it is difficult to implement this kind of dynamic layout. and he suggested:

1. either let shop owner chooses layout first and populate content. A new app has to be published in order to change to different layout, there will be problem of supporting previous installed app.
2. or use a global config file that contains global app setting such as products layout and  iphone app requests it periodically.

Without much iOS development experience, I would like to get your opinion on what is possible here. Thanks.

**Some More Questions**

- How to do View Initialization before getting the data? Or is that a real problem one should worry?
- There are cache for these dynamic views and that may cause problem when shop owner made the change in CMS and users still have the view cached. How to deal with this kind of problem? never cache or force reload upon problem?

Comment: Your requirement just means the app has a little bit of logic to process the downloaded data to decide which of 2 view controllers to show. That's less than 10 lines of code.

Comment: You can handle this dynamically quite easily. You don't need pure dynamic layout generations. You just have to change UITableViewCell style, which is quite easy.

Comment: Your friend doesn't know what he's talking about.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I have added two more related questions in the original post.